# Motorola Moto G200 brick with error "No valid operating system"

Tags: boot-loop, motorola-moto-g, bootloader-lock, android-12, motorola

I need help with Motorola Moto G200 whose bootloader stopped working after a bad overclock using the KonaBess app. I have tried to turn it on by myself, and I have even taken it to a technical service, but there is no case.

Attached is the error when turning on:

> No valid operating system.

I tried RSI, CMD, and EPROM, and they all end with the same error message.

I am an amateur technician and I still do not specialize in these delicate issues, but I think I have burned the GPU or some internal interconnection of my smartphone. At the time of flashing the ROM, the `vendor`, `boot.img`, and `bootloader.img` fail in chain, and the `superpacks` are loaded correctly until the fifth, the sixth package or `superpack` does not load and dies there.

Comment: Sounds like the eMMC storage or the mainboard itself is bad... Attempting to repair this yourself is going to be almost impossible, and in most cases if a service center won't do a mainboard swap under warranty, it's likely not economically repairable.